# Open a file in a text editor when a button is clicked on Pyqt5

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5

I have a window on PyQt5. On clicking a button, it should open in a text editor.The file which is to be opened is stored in a folder whose location is same as the program location. Only the file name is stored in sqlite3 database. How to open this file whose name is stored in sqlite3 database and the file is stored inside a current folder . I need to open a file in text editor when a pushButton is pressed. What to do to fix this. Please help!!

Comment: Provide your code, then you would get help.

Comment: what is `text editor`?